# How can I fix my PATCH request to append to ArrayField, rather than delete and replace the whole object?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with my PATCH request instance. Currently, data that is being PATCHED and sent from a request is overriding every item in my list of strings `ArrayField` inside my model object.

I need my patch request behavior to append to the rest of the items in `ArrayField` object, not delete/override.

How can I go about doing that?

I assume I need to override the patch method within `RetrieveUpdateAPIView`,
so I've started out here:

```
     def patch(self, request, **kwargs):
         item = self.kwargs.get('slug')
         serializer = StockListSerializer(item, data=request.data, partial=True)

         if serializer.is_valid():
             serializer.save()
             Response(serializer, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
         return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer.py:

```
class StringArrayField(serializers.ListField):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        obj = super().to_representation(obj)
        return ",".join([str(element) for element in obj])

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = data.split(",")
        return super().to_internal_value(data)

class StockListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stock_list = StringArrayField()

    class Meta:
        model = Bucket
        fields = ("stock_list",)
```

view.py

```
class EditBucketSymbols(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = StockListSerializer
    queryset = Bucket.objects.all()

    def get_object(self, queryset=queryset, **kwargs):
         item = self.kwargs.get('slug')
         return get_object_or_404(Bucket, slug=item)
```

url.py:

```
path('bucket/symbols/<str:slug>/', EditBucketSymbols.as_view(), name='editsymbols')
```

model.py:

```
stock_list = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=6,null=True),size=30,null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: when you do `StockListSerializer(item, data=request.data, partial=True)` it takes the existing object and updates it with the given `request.data`. What you can do to solve this is take the existing value present in the model attribute and append it to the incoming data(`request.data`) inside `to_internal_value`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the great recommendation. I'm having trouble referencing the specific model attribute for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the ***field-lever validation*** technique here,

```
class StockListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stock_list = StringArrayField()

    class Meta:
        model = Bucket
        fields = ("stock_list",)

    def validate_stock_list(self, stock_list):
        existing_stock_list = []
        if self.instance and self.instance.stock_list:
            # Patch or Put request
            existing_stock_list = self.instance.stock_list
        return existing_stock_list + stock_list
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to add  `if self.instance.stock_list is not None:` because you cannot append an Nonetype list. If that is the case, then I just returned the validated data and did not append.

Comment: Thanks for that edge case @woof I just updated the answer a bit. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I would do this within the `.validate()` method of the serializer. something like:

```py
def validate(self, validated_data):
  # Make sure that this only runs for Patch requests
  if self.context["request"].method == "PATCH"

    # Get list of existing stocks from instance and append incoming list
    stock_list = self.instance.stock_list + validated_data["stock_list"]

    # Replace data
    validated_data["stock_list"] = stock_list
  
  return validated_data
```

Comment: Hi Mortiz, where do you recommend I add this, to my view or serializer?

Comment: To StockListSerializer as described here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#object-level-validation
Serializers support validation, Views do not at all, not in django itself and neither in DRF